# Socket can't connect to ServerSocket when .accept()

Tags: java, serversocket

this is my simple code:

```
package NetworkProgramming;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class CommunicationServer {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1617);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted");
    }

}
```

The program just stuck in server.accept().
I have tried to do:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);
```

and it succeed, but when I do `socket = server.accept();` it just stuck!

What the problem with that code?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Please look on these codes:

If you are programming a server, then this is how you open a socket:

```
ServerSocket MyService;
try {
   MyServerice = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
```

When implementing a server you also need to create a socket object from the ServerSocket in order to listen for and accept connections from clients.

```
Socket clientSocket = null;
try {
   serviceSocket = MyService.accept();
    }
catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

It from [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html)

I have done the same but it doesnt work...

Comment: ServerSocket accept() is a blocking call , waits for a incoming connection. What is the problem?

Comment: I have tried to connect! but altought it stuck.

Answer (score 0):

At first run your server class CommunicationServer then run below client class    MyClient.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 public class MyClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1617);

        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        s.close();
        dout.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `new Socket(ip,port)` you create a new Socket that connects to the server with the ip and the port. The other solution with `server.accept()`let the server wait for a connection with is never done and returns this found socket (if someone connects too). This are two total different things you compare. Look at the API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int)) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept())